# Facebook - oauth Multiple Users - Single Ruby on Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, oauth

**Situation:**
I have an app built in Ruby on Rails that's run on a tablet device in a public location - meaning multiple people use the same app. When someone uses the app they are asked to login to Facebook so it can retrieve some data from their profile. This is done via oauth authentication process.

**Problem:**
The problem is the authentication process keeps the user logged into their Facebook account. This means that when someone else comes along and uses the app, the previous user will still be logged in to their Facebook account (not desirable as their account an be "hijacked"). This will also cause the app to use the previous users account.

I'm looking for a way to programatically log the user out of their Facebook account once the authentication and data retrieval process is completed. Should look like the following:

**Desired Process:**

1. User submits form
2. oauth authentication
3. collect info
4. logout of Facebook

I've seen some "hacky" solutions such as redirecting to facebook's logout.php script, but it's my understanding that this changes over time which would cause it to fail once it does.

I've also looked into re-authentication - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/, but that seems like a poor user experience.

Any suggestions on a solid way to programatically log a user out of Facebook?

Comment: Actually persistence is important for various other usecases. Unless the user logs out, don't log out.

Comment: Yeah I can see that for other use cases, but this one it's undesirable.

Comment: I have the same problem, nobody find a solution?